# Difference between pearson correlation and shapley

Tags: pearsons-correlation-coefficient

When we say pearson correlation we are talking about the correlation between input with other inputs or an output. Ok. Does that necessarily mean if we have + value of Pearson between input A and output B, then increase in A leads to increase in B and negative value means vice versa? But, I normally was told that they show the effect on prediction not value. Anybody could make me clear?
How about shapley. I am sure that it shows the importance of the input on the output. So, does "importance" mean it is more sensitive to that input? Also, red and blue dots show the effect of increase decrease of inputs on the increase or decrease of output

Comment: where are the 'red and blue dots'?

Answer (score 1):

Pearson correlation is a measure of the **linear correlation between two variables**. A positive value indicates a positive linear relationship (as one variable increases, so does the other), while a negative value indicates a negative linear relationship (as one variable increases, the other decreases). However, correlation does not imply **causation** which means just because two variables are correlated, it doesn't mean that changes in one variable cause changes in the other.

Shapley values, on the other hand, provide a way to **fairly distribute the contribution of each feature to the prediction for a particular instance.**

In the context of machine learning, the **importance** of a feature generally refers to how much the model's prediction changes when the feature's value is changed. So yes, you could say that a more important feature is one that the model is more sensitive to.

Comment: you said A positive value indicates a positive linear relationship (as one variable increases, so does the other), then just because two variables are correlated, it doesn't mean that changes in one variable cause changes in the other. What does that mean? it means necessarily they do not effect each other? But when we know they cause or not!?

Comment: "Correlation does not imply causation" means that just because two things appear to be related to each other, it doesn't necessarily mean that one is directly causing the other to happen. For example, if data shows that people who eat more ice cream also go swimming more often, this doesn't mean eating ice cream causes people to swim. There could be a third factor involved, like hot weather, that influences both ice cream consumption and swimming. So, while the two variables (ice cream eating and swimming) are correlated, one does not cause the other.